# How to programatically perform .onDelete animation on List in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have 2 ways to delete an item in the List

1. Swipe. It's achieved by .onDelete modifier and works fine
2. Custom Delete button on each List Item.

By tapping on the custom Delete button, how can I programmatically perform the .onDelete with UITableView default deleting animation?

**Important:** I don't mean just using withAnimation. I mean default animation for row deleting on the List, when row became red and collapsing.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var countries = ["USA", "Canada", "England", "Cameroon", "South Africa", "Mexico" , "Japan", "South Korea"]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(countries, id: \.self) { country in
                    HStack {
                        Text(country)
                        Spacer()
                        Button {
                            //What to put here to trigger default deleting animation?
                        } label: {
                            Text("Delete")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: self.deleteItem)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Countries", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
    private func deleteItem(at indexSet: IndexSet){
        self.countries.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perform actually the same with animation, like

```
Button {
  withAnimation {
    self.countries.removeAll { $0 == country }    // << here !!
  }
} label: {
    Text("Delete")
}
```

in the case of other animations implicit `withAnimation` in `Button` should be removed and used explicit one per model value, like

```
List {
    ForEach(countries, id: \.self) { country in
      // other code ...
    }
    .onDelete(perform: self.deleteItem)
}
.animation(.default, value: countries) // << here !!
```

Comment: It did not work for me. No animation, I've tried already(((

Comment: Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5 - works fine.

Comment: I just have other animations at the same operation and this one does not work simultaneously with them... When swiping works perfect. Using withAnimation works only when disable all other animations.

Comment: And I've tried to make withAnimation working, but that's not what I want. I want default List deleting animation like row became red and collapsing. Not just view disappearing animation

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this approach to `I want default List deleting animation like row became red and collapsing.`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.editMode) var editMode  // <-- here
    
    @State var countries = ["USA", "Canada", "England", "Cameroon", "South Africa", "Mexico" , "Japan", "South Korea"]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(countries, id: \.self) { country in
                    HStack {
                        Text(country)
                        Spacer()
                        Button {
                            // -- here
                            editMode?.wrappedValue = .active == editMode?.wrappedValue ? .inactive : .active
                        } label: {
                            Text("Delete")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: self.deleteItem)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Countries", displayMode: .inline)
         // .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton()) // <-- here if desired
        }
    }
    private func deleteItem(at indexSet: IndexSet){
        self.countries.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I need to Delete once button pressed, not to enter Edit mode.